# RealmProxy error on Realm Object

Tags: java, android, realm

Im currently creating a realm object that takes another realm object however when i run the project i get a null pointer with the realm proxy error on the parent object. Ive checked all of the getters and setters for both objects and they are using the android studio generated ones. Can anyone suggest why this error may be appearing.

Parent object

```
public class FavouriteObject extends RealmObject {

    private String ID;
    private String type;
    private CategoryObject categoryObject;

    public FavouriteObject(){}

    public void setID(String ID){
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getID(){
        return ID;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public void setCategoryObject(CategoryObject categoryObject){
        this.categoryObject = categoryObject;
    }

    public CategoryObject getCategoryObject(){
        return categoryObject;
    }

}
```

Child Object

```
public class CategoryObject extends RealmObject {

    private String dateAdded;
    private String description;
    private String detailImage;
    private String featured;
    private String image;
    private String langID;
    private String navigateUrl;
    private String specialFeature;
    private String supplierName;
    private String weekAdded;
    private String title;

    private String id;
    private boolean newProduct;

    public void setNewProduct(boolean newProduct){
        this.newProduct = newProduct;
    }

    public boolean isNewProduct() {
        return newProduct;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(String dateAdded){
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public String getDateAdded(){
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public void setDetailImage(String detailImage){
        this.detailImage = detailImage;
    }

    public String getDetailImage(){
        return detailImage;
    }

    public void setFeatured(String featured){
        this.featured = featured;
    }

    public String getFeatured(){
        return featured;
    }

    public void setImage(String image){
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getImage(){
        return image;
    }

    public void setLangID(String langID) {
        this.langID = langID;
    }

    public String getLangID(){
        return langID;
    }

    public void setNavigateUrl(String navigateUrl){
        this.navigateUrl = navigateUrl;
    }

    public String getNavigateUrl(){
        return navigateUrl;
    }

    public void setSpecialFeature(String specialFeature) {
        this.specialFeature = specialFeature;
    }

    public String getSpecialFeature(){
        return specialFeature;
    }

    public void setSupplierName(String supplierName) {
        this.supplierName = supplierName;
    }

    public String getSupplierName(){
        return supplierName;
    }

    public void setWeekAdded(String weekAdded) {
        this.weekAdded = weekAdded;
    }

    public String getWeekAdded(){
        return weekAdded;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Adding the Object

```
realm.beginTransaction();
FavouritesObject favourite = realm.createObject(FavouritesObject.class);
favourite.setID(po.getID());
favourite.setType("microsite");
favourite.setCategoryObject(productsObject.get(position));
```

The Error Message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.realm.FavouritesObjectRealmProxy.setCategoryObject(FavouritesObjectRealmProxy.java:64)
        at com.test.project.Adapters.CategoryAdapter$1.onClick(CategoryAdapter.java:101)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have also tried to create a test object that only had one variable however i still had the same issue. Any help would be great!

Comment: Please post the code that uses these objects and the error message. The models are fine.

Comment: @bmunk Ive now edited the question with more details. Thanks

Comment: What is productsObject.get(position) that you pass to setCategoryObject()?

Comment: Did you look at the code here FavouritesObjectRealmProxy.java, line 64?

Comment: @bmunk it returns a CategoryObject. Also regarding line 64 i cant access FavouritesObjectRealmProxy as i believe that is created by Realm.

Comment: But have you checked that it returns an object and not null? Even if it's generated by Realm, you can still see the generated code.

Comment: @bmunk There is an object returned. Also though it shows that FavouritesObjectRealmProxy is clickable above in my post, in the actual log this is just standard text. Is there any other way of accessing this class. Many thanks for helping by the way!

Comment: @bmunk now solved! i was being a fool and wasn't creating the CategoryObject through realm and instead creating it normally i.e new CategoryObject. Thanks for the suggestions though =)

Comment: But we could maybe check and give a better error message. I've made a [github Issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/883) to track that.

Comment: I'd think you don't have a value assigned to `productsObject`. That's why you get NPE. Please post the code where you fetch `productsObject`

Answer (score 2):

The line `favourite.setCategoryObject(productsObject.get(position));` seems to be the issue.

The value you get from `productsObject.get(position)`, is it coming from Realm (i.e. has it been created as a result of `RealmResult<ProductsObject>` or `realm.createObject(ProductsObject.class)` or similar).

You'll know that the object is being created by Realm if the `io.realm.internal.Row row` and the `io.realm.Realm realm` properties that your ProductsObject inherits from the RealmObject isn't null.

I suggest changing this section:

```
favourite.setType("microsite");
favourite.setCategoryObject(productsObject.get(position));
```

to

```
favourite.setType("microsite");
ProductsObject po = productsObject.get(position);
favourite.setCategoryObject(po);
```

then set a break point on the line `ProductsObject po = productsObject.get(position);` to see if the either the `row` or `realm` property (inherited from `RealmObject`) on the `po` object is null.  If any or both of them is null then you need to update the function to ensure that your `productsObject.get(position)` function returns a value created by Realm.